# Output directory is not specified in idea project

Tags: intellij-idea, java-web-start

It has a problem in idea:

> Error:(3, 8) java: 写入edu.nuaa.vo.User时出错: Output directory is not
>   specified

What does it mean?

My compiler Out path is:

[image]

Comment: This Chinese means that :"writing into edu.nuaa.vo.User has a error",ths:p

Comment: Check what directory is specified in each [modules's **Paths tab**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/paths-tab.html#d406203e13) for the compiler output.

Answer (score 8):

Had a similar problem. What helped me is creating the folder in your project (on the same level with the '**src**' folder) named '**out**' and it started working. Initially it was missing for some reason.

[image: project structure]

Comment: Thank you. It is magic!..
What is the reason of such behavior?